# Setting CPU frequency guidelines

Tags: hardware, cpu, power-management, cpu-frequency

I'm changing my CPU frequency because of noisy fan.

I used `sudo cpufreq-selector -g powersave` for this purpose, but I replaced my Linux system Xubuntu with Lubuntu because it utilizes better resources. My version is 11.10 and I'm not using GNOME nor KDE nor Xfce nor LXDE (only xmonad).

There is something wrong with `cpufreq-selector`

```
$ cpufreq-selector

Failed to acquire org.gnome.CPUFreqSelector: Connection ":1.35" is not
allowed to own the service "org.gnome.CPUFreqSelector" due to
security policies in the configuration file
```

`cpufreq-info` shows:

```
$ cpufreq-info

cpufrequtils 007: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik
Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
driver: acpi-cpufreq
CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
hardware limits: 600 MHz - 1.60 GHz
available frequency steps: 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 800 MHz, 600 MHz
available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave,
performance   current policy: frequency should be within 1.60 GHz and 1.60 GHz.
The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
within this range.
current CPU frequency is 1.60 GHz.
cpufreq stats: 1.60 GHz:98.40%, 1.40 GHz:0.02%, 1.20 GHz:1.58%, 800
MHz:0.01%, 600 MHz:0.00% (38)
```

I also tried [this](http://technowizah.com/2007/01/debian-how-to-cpu-frequency-management.html) guide because my processor is the same (only the frequency is 1.6 instead of 1.73). I'm not sure if something happened after

`sudo modprobe speedstep_centrino` command.

Could you help me to figure out what's wrong here and why I can't slow the frequency down?

Comment: the same happens on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS....

Answer (score 2):

`org.gnome.CPUFreqSelector` sounds like DBus but googling revealed it could be a PolicyKit issue.  [Maybe this helps, granting the applet CPUFreq changes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling#Privilege_Granting_Under_GNOME).

I think you don't need the `cpufreq-selector` tool, you could just [use `cpufreq-set` directly](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils) (maybe with `sudo`, I'm not sure). (Or the [`cpupowerutils`](http://lwn.net/Articles/433002/) frontend, alive [here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree;f=tools/power/cpupower;hb=HEAD))

(**Edit** to match your updated question)

- `modprobe` not outputting anything indicates that everything went fine (try `echo $?` after the `modprobe`, it should be `0` indicating success; also `dmesg` could contain something; also `lsmod`'s output should be different afterwards, indicating that the module is loaded).
- Have you tried `modprobe`ing an actual governor, i.e., `modprobe cpufreq_powersave` (after `modprobe`ing your `speedstep_centrino`)? (The respective `cpufreq-set -g powersave` should work then.)

Comment: 1) There is a problem to switch to the directory `polkit-1` 2) [cpufreq-set](http://pastebin.com/rt9TcTv6) 3) [cpupowerutils](http://gitorious.org/cpupowerutils/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any further. Best try to fix the polkit issue, I'd have guessed the `cpufreq-set` doesn't honor it, but maybe it does after all... (How about `cpufreq-set -g powersave` and `lsmod | grep cpufreq` to check if the modules are loaded?)

Comment: 1) `cpufreq-set -g powersave` outputs the same error 2) `lsmod | grep cpufreq` founds nothing

Comment: 2) That could be the problem.  Try `modprobe cpufreq_userspace` (or `cpufreq_powersave`) and `cpufreq-set -u 1.20GHz` (or `-g powersave`) afterwards  ([more information about the needed modules](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling#CPU_frequency_driver), maybe the one I mentioned is not enough)

Comment: When running `modprobe` I can't see any output and nothing changed. I also edited the question with guide I tried to apply and where it stuck.

Comment: Sounds good, see edit `:)`

Comment: after `modprobe` `echo $?` returns `0`. `dmesg` returns many things. I was looking for `speedstep_centrino` but it's not there. Similarly `lsmod` and similarly with `modprobe cpufreq_powersave`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1923/discussion-between-sr-and-xralf)