# Loading speedstep_centrino kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, cpu-frequency

Because of a noisy fan in my laptop, I need to change CPU frequency and for this task I need to load the appropriate kernel module.

The CPU in my laptop Acer TravelMate 4002WLMi is:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.60GHz
```

[This](http://technowizah.com/2007/01/debian-how-to-cpu-frequency-management.html) article helped me to find the kernel module I need (my CPU differs only a little in frequency).

After the `sudo modprobe speedstep_centrino` command nothing happened. `echo $?` returns `0`.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/2B4W5KWa) is the output of `lsmod` and [dmesg](http://pastebin.com/xYfdxTrm) and [other](http://pastebin.com/VHJLm7aH) useful outputs.

Could you explain what's wrong with kernel modules and how to use the appropriate module for changing CPU frequency?

Comment: Anything show up in `dmesg` and/or `/var/log/messages` or wherever your system logs are stored?

Comment: @Mat See question edit, `/var/log/messages` file is not present.

Comment: From the `modprobe` manpage: `Usually modprobe only prints messages if something goes wrong.` So, i would assume that the module was loaded fine. What does `modprobe -v` tell? Are the `dmesg` and `lsmod` output from the same session as the `modprobe`?

Comment: @tohuwawohu `-v` makes no difference. Yes, session is the same.

Comment: hmm - ok, 11.10 in fact doesn't log to `/var/log/messages`; but `/var/log/syslog` should be there - anything interesting there? If not, i fear i can't help any further. The blog entry you've linked did mention the `acpi_cpufreq` module - maybe this works? Are any modules blacklisted?

Comment: @tohuwawohu `sudo modprobe -v speedstep_centrino` adds nothing new to `/var/log/syslog`. With `acpi_cpufreq` I have the same result. How can I find out if the modules are blacklisted? I noticed in my `dmesg` the message `Notice: NX (Execute Disable) protection missing in CPU!`.

Comment: @xralf: just to make sure - modprobe won't output anything if the module was loaded successfully. So you should check the output of `lsmod` and/or `dmesg` anyway to see if the module is there.

Comment: @tohuwawohu I tried `lsmod > lsmod01.txt; dmesg > dmesg01.txt; sudo modprobe speedstep_centrino; lsmod > lsmod02.txt; dmesg > dmesg02.txt; diff lsmod01.txt lsmod02.txt; diff dmesg01.txt dmesg02.txt` with no difference

Comment: @xralf: is speedstep activated in BIOS? Another point: there may be [bugs in the 3.0 Kernel regarding speedstep_centrino](http://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2011/08/msg00763.html).

Comment: @tohuwawohu In my `Phoenix` BIOS there is not such option. If there is a bug, there should exist some alternative module that is working, because I used Xubuntu before and I was able to change frequency.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1941/discussion-between-tohuwawohu-and-xralf)

Comment: what `modinfo speedstep_centrino` give ? that should give you some information on the module & some parameters the module can take. Also try to use `insmod` instead of `modprobe` and see if there is any error message.  As far as i can see the logs aren't aware about the module.

Comment: are you insist on using just that particular method to change the frequency ? if i could come up with something else is it OK ?

Comment: @HananN. I have another question for using another [method](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/setting-cpu-frequency-guidelines) In this question I'd like to load the appropriate kernel module.

Comment: Just load `acpi_cpufreq`, and check if frequency is reduced by /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: Noisy fan: Either the fan is working overtime (air flow obstructed, dirt in the machine) or its bearing is giving out.